# Group by or combine multi array?

Tags: php, arrays

here's me with a problem I have to sort a table based on:

1- competence

2 level of "palier"

I have this array:

```
[C2.1] => Array
        (
            [palier] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 1
                    [1] => 2
                    [2] => 1
                )

            [note] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 12.00
                    [1] => 13.00
                    [2] => 15.00
                )


        )
```

and i'd would like :

```
[C2.1] => Array
        (
            [palier] => Array
                (
                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [note] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => 12.00
                                    [1] => 15.00

                                )

                        )

                      [2] => Array
                        (
                            [note] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => 13.00

                                )

                         )

        )
```

I get my first array with this code

```
foreach ($row5 as $key =>$values)
{
    $val3 = preg_split('/;|,/', $values['cve']);
    $val5 = preg_split('/;|,/', $values['note']);
    $val6 = preg_split('/;|,/', $values['palier']);
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($val3); $i++)
    {

$resultat2[$val3[$i]]['palier'][]= $val6[$i];  
$resultat2[$val3[$i]]['note'][] = $val5[$i];
$resultat2[$val3[$i]]['nombre'] = count($resultat2[$val3[$i]]['note']);
$resultat2[$val3[$i]]['moyenne'] = round(array_sum($resultat2[$val3[$i]]['note'])/count($resultat2[$val3[$i]]['note']),2);
    }

}
```

but I can not have my second array help please!

Comment: You should add a tag for the programming language.

Comment: You cannot make such requested array since key "palier" appears twice in that array.

Comment: ok but how to do ?

Comment: But why do you want it

Comment: ok i change my array 2 how do I get the array 2

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($c21['palier'] as $p=>$group) {
  if (!array_key_exists($group, $result)) {
    $result[$group] = array('note' => array());
  }
  $result[$group]['note'][] = $c21['note'][$p];
}
```

Could also be done with iterators or so, but let's KISS ♥.